# How do I print each element of list in a new line with pysimplegui?

Tags: python, list, printing, format, pysimplegui

Hey guys I'm having a really simple problem thats driving me crazy though.
I'm basically just trying to create a pop up window with PySimpleGui that prints each element of a list in a new line. I know that when using an ordinary print statement, this can be done very easily with a for loop or e.g. print(*list,sep="\n")
 However, I simply cant figure out a way when trying to implement the print statement within my PySimpleGui pop up window.
Here´s my code

> import PySimpleGUI as sg
>
> a=[3,45,23,1,8,9]
>
> sg.PopupScrolled("Synchronization completed",
>                    f"The following items have been added: \n",
>                    f"{a}")

So how do I manage to format the pop up code so that each element of my list [a] is printed in a new line?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If the answer below helps, please upvote and accept so that SO can close this issue

Comment: I did... it's a good solution.  I would have been lazy and removed the variable s and put it all in the PopupScrolled call.

Comment: I got even lazier and implemented the solution you were hoping for.... indicating a list to be printed by using  *list  syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

a=[3,45,23,1,8,9]
s = '\n'.join([str(i) for i in a])# pass the string instead of an array.
sg.PopupScrolled("Synchronization completed", f"The following items have been added: \n", f"{s}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... just noticed in the post how the OP wanted to do it was the same as the normal call to print.  The sample given was:

```
print(*list,sep="\n")
```

If that's what you want to do, then you can do exactly that with your code.  Popups take any kinds of values, not just strings.  It's just like a print.  So, you can change your example print statement into the Popup Scrolled call.

It's a single line of code, just like the print call:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

a=[3,45,23,1,8,9]

sg.PopupScrolled(*a, title="Synchronization completed")
```